# Rails: root :to => "controller#method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A few questions about this route:

```
root  :to  => "controller#method"
```

1. When a GET request is made in what part of Rails does it equate GET "/" with `root`?
2. What is `root` (i.e. a variable, method, other)?

Comment: 1. Router does that. 2. `root` is a method.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev by `Router` do you mean the Router class in rails4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb?

Answer (score 2):

root as well as match define verb-independent routes, meaning all http verbs are included in the routing rule. If you want to define verb-dependant rules, you can use get/post/put/delete rules like:

```
get 'profile', to: 'users#show'
```

In particular, root defines what the default page (when you acess the root path of your application) is.

You can find all the information you need here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html